# How can I copy some dependencies to my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, twitter-bootstrap, package.json

I'm following a great course (Django/react ecommerce on udemy), however the bootstrap version that they're using is really old and a lot of stuff doesn't work on newer versions. I saw the dependencies on Github but all are conflicting when I'm trying to install with NPM. I can try and force some but it'll probably make things worse. Is there a way I "copy/paste" their package.json and run `npm install` or something to get the same dependencies on my project?

I can refactor everything to newer versions of course but that'll take triple the time to finish the course.

Answer (score 0):

By default npm installs packages using ^ which means any version in the same major range, you can switch this behaviour by using --save-exact

eg: `npm install --save --save-exact react`

[This Blog may help you!](https://www.dalejefferson.com/articles/2018-02-04-how-to-save-exact-npm-package-versions/)

And if you wish to install specific version-

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

eg: `npm install express@3.0.0`